# Why would one add a custom system call to Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls

So I followed an online tutorial on implementing a custom syscall on Arch Linux that simply takes a string and prints it to the kernel log. After completing the tutorial and testing out the syscall, I was left wondering in what situations do kernel devs say "Oh, lets change how this syscall works" or "We need to add another one". I am familiar with the concepts of **userspace** and **kernelspace** and why syscalls exist in the first place, but the benefits of new ones are beyond me. I would appreciate any insight on the matter, even a reason why some of the existing syscalls were added or modified and how it affected the overall state of the kernel.

Comment: An Operating System evolves, and provides more functionality. If some new functionality cannot be implemented with current set of syscalls, a new syscall is added.

Answer (score 0):

Your instincts are good, nurture them.  Only under extreme pressure should a kernels interface be extended.  Increasing the surface of the kernel increases the attack potential, needlessly complicates already complicated software, and is rarely a net benefit.

Micro-kernels, or even small-interface kernels (like plan9) have delivered on reduced attack surface, serviceability and reliability.  The original architect of UNIX wrote a fantastic paper on why the kernel must be minimal.  Everything discussed in the domain of least-privilege reaches out to minimal kernels.